# Verbosity pandas apply

Tags: python, pandas

I'm doing a relatively heavy apply on a big pandas Series. Is there any way to get back some print feedback on how far it is outside of doing a print inside the function everytime it is called?

Comment: I don't think so, no.

Comment: That is unfortunate, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could wrap your function with a tracer. Two examples below, one based on number of iterations completed, and one based on the percentage of total work.

```
from pandas import Series

def progress_coroutine(print_on = 10000):
    print "Starting progress monitor"

    iterations = 0
    while True:
        yield
        iterations += 1
        if (iterations % print_on == 0):
            print "{} iterations done".format(iterations)

def percentage_coroutine(to_process, print_on_percent = 0.10):
    print "Starting progress percentage monitor"

    processed = 0
    count = 0
    print_count = to_process*print_on_percent
    while True:
        yield
        processed += 1
        count += 1
        if (count >= print_count):
            count = 0
            pct = (float(processed)/float(to_process))*100

            print "{}% finished".format(pct)

def trace_progress(func, progress = None):
    def callf(*args, **kwargs):
        if (progress is not None):
            progress.send(None)

        return func(*args, **kwargs)

    return callf

def my_func(i):
    return i * 2

data_series = Series(xrange(100000))
co1 = progress_coroutine()
co1.next()
co2 = percentage_coroutine(len(data_series))
co2.next()
data_series.apply(trace_progress(my_func, progress = co1))
data_series.apply(trace_progress(my_func, progress = co2))

Starting progress monitor
Starting progress percentage monitor
10000 iterations done
20000 iterations done
30000 iterations done
40000 iterations done
50000 iterations done
60000 iterations done
70000 iterations done
80000 iterations done
90000 iterations done
100000 iterations done
10.0% finished
20.0% finished
30.0% finished
40.0% finished
50.0% finished
60.0% finished
70.0% finished
80.0% finished
90.0% finished
100.0% finished
```

Answer (score 2):

I made changes to the code above for Python 3, in case anyone wants to use. Thank you @Clockw3rk for the above answer

```
from pandas import Series

def progress_coroutine(print_on = 10):
    print ("Starting progress monitor")

    iterations = 0
    while True:
        yield
        iterations += 1
        if (iterations % print_on == 0):
            print ("{} iterations done".format(iterations))

def percentage_coroutine(to_process, print_on_percent = 0.10):
    print ("Starting progress percentage monitor")

    processed = 0
    count = 0
    print_count = to_process*print_on_percent
    while True:
        yield
        processed += 1
        count += 1
        if (count >= print_count):
            count = 0
            pct = (float(processed)/float(to_process))*100

            print ("{}% finished".format(pct))

def trace_progress(func, progress = None):
    def callf(*args, **kwargs):
        if (progress is not None):
            progress.send(None)

        return func(*args, **kwargs)

    return callf

def my_func(i):
    return i ** 2

data_series = Series(list(range(100)))
co1 = progress_coroutine()
co2 = percentage_coroutine(len(data_series))
data_series.apply(trace_progress(my_func, progress = co1))
data_series.apply(trace_progress(my_func, progress = co2))

Starting progress monitor
10 iterations done
20 iterations done
30 iterations done
40 iterations done
50 iterations done
60 iterations done
70 iterations done
80 iterations done
90 iterations done
Starting progress percentage monitor
10.0% finished
20.0% finished
30.0% finished
40.0% finished
50.0% finished
60.0% finished
70.0% finished
80.0% finished
90.0% finished
Out[12]:
0        0
1        1
2        4
3        9
4       16
5       25
6       36
7       49
8       64
9       81
10     100
11     121
12     144
13     169
14     196
15     225
16     256
17     289
18     324
19     361
20     400
21     441
22     484
23     529
24     576
25     625
26     676
27     729
28     784
29     841
      ... 
70    4900
71    5041
72    5184
73    5329
74    5476
75    5625
76    5776
77    5929
78    6084
79    6241
80    6400
81    6561
82    6724
83    6889
84    7056
85    7225
86    7396
87    7569
88    7744
89    7921
90    8100
91    8281
92    8464
93    8649
94    8836
95    9025
96    9216
97    9409
98    9604
99    9801
Length: 100, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

if you need a simple progress bar:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
tqdm.pandas()
df.progress_apply(my_fun)
```

eg. to apply translation

[image]